# Compile zxing library after changes in android

Tags: android, compilation, zxing

I am modifying the zxing library to make the scanner to appear in portrait mode.
[I have followed this step by step tuto :](http://www.rqgg.net/topic/pkwtq-how-to-show-zxing-camera-in-portrait-mode-android.html)

The problem I am having is that on runtime, when trying to show the camera, I am getting this error :

```
05-23 05:21:42.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1849): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 05:21:42.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1849): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.novationmobile.vowchr/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-23 05:21:42.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1849): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-23 05:21:42.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at com.novationmobile.vowchr.VowchrApplication.onSharedPreferenceChanged(VowchrApplication.java:103)
05-23 05:21:42.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at android.app.ContextImpl$SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(ContextImpl.java:2830)
05-23 05:21:42.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at android.preference.PreferenceManager.setNoCommit(PreferenceManager.java:484)
05-23 05:21:42.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:255)
05-23 05:21:42.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at android.preference.PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(PreferenceManager.java:444)
05-23 05:21:42.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at android.preference.PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(PreferenceManager.java:422)
05-23 05:21:42.191: E/AndroidRuntime(1849):     at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.onCreate(CaptureActivity.java:169)
```

..........

This is the code 169 line in CaptureActivity :  PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);

I think this is happening since I am not compiling the zxing library after modifing the files. I just added a comment to see if the code modification was causing the error and it happened again.

If this is true, how is it supposed I should compile my changes ?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a jar or a library project?

Comment: Newcomers to Java should spend time learning Java. The problem is in your code, in `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` of `VowchrApplication`. You can tell that by reading the stack trace. Hence, the problem would not appear to be in ZXing, or any changes you made to ZXing, but in your own code that you wrote that you have a bug in.

Comment: it is a library project, so I can modify those files and I can see that the changes I did are reflected on the jar file that is shown on dependencies section (but I can not modify the files inside the jar)

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks for your answer. But I have no problems to run the application and showing the camera view before modifying a single line on the library. Once I modify any single line adding a comment, the problem appears.

Comment: So? Read the stack trace. See that the `NullPointerException` is in line 103 of `VowchrApplication.java`. Examine that line and see what could be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Read your stack trace. It's an error in your code and nothing to do with the library:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at com.novationmobile.vowchr.VowchrApplication.onSharedPreferenceChanged(VowchrApplication.java:103)
```

You may also not be actually compiling the code as you think, but that's your second problem.

Please avoid copying our `android/` application completely. It's not encouraged, and depending on the extent of your copying, not permitted by the license.

Comment: Ok, I will check and debug my code. What was making some noise, was the fact that when modifying the code on the library was causing the issue. And without modifications on it, it works perfectly with no crashes. And about copying the android/ app I apologize if I did it, I am just learning about integrating zxing library and I did not realize about that. Once I dominate this lib integration I promess to delete everything required to be according the licence. Thanks for your answers guys and sorry about my short experience in eclipse.